# Mercurial HG Update Exited With Status 255

Tags: mercurial, permissions

When remotely updating a Mercurial Repository, I am getting the following error from the `hg update` command that is being run on the remote server after the push.  I looked around online for some help for this however was unsuccessful in finding anything useful.  At this point, I am hoping for some ideas and / or insight as to what would be causing this problem.

The error is just below.  It occurred when pushing two changesets.  One changeset included an unrelated index.html file change.  The other changeset was a merge, which included the index.html change as well as the renaming of the two image files.

```
levinaris@server01:/home/web/repository$ hg push
pushing to ssh://10.10.1.12//home/web/repository
searching for changes`remote: adding changesets
remote: adding manifests
remote: adding file changes
remote: added 2 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files
remote: abort: Operation not permitted: /home/web/repository/html/images/image.gif
remote: warning: changegroup hook exited with status 255
```

Additional details:

- Both images are 10385 bytes in size.  (yes, this error occurs on two images I have)
- The two images had their names changed in changesets that were already pushed and `hg update`d due to case-folding collisions when attempting to pull the repositories down to Windows PCs.
- The target server has the following hook in /etc/mercurial/hgrc:

  ```
  [hooks]
  changegroup = hg update
  ```
- As a work-around, I did the following:

  1. Deleted image.gif.
  2. Deleted another image file that produced the error.
  3. Ran `hg update` - success!
  4. Ran `hg revert html/image/image.gif`
  5. Ran `hg revert html/image/otherimage.gif`

At this point, I am trying to better understand the cause of this problem, so that I can ensure a solid, easy-to-use implementation in my environment.  I really appreciate your help!!

---

After using `hg --debug update` in the hook, I received this output:

```
levinaris@server01:/home/web/repository$ hg push
pushing to /home/web/staging/repository
searching for changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 2 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files
resolving manifests
 overwrite False partial False
 ancestor 58a5edb95c9a local 58a5edb95c9a+ remote 3aafb97b148c
  searching for copies back to rev 6
 html/index.php: remote is newer -> g
 html/images/otherimage.gif.casefolding: update permissions -> e
 html/images/image.gif: update permissions -> e
abort: Operation not permitted: /home/web/staging/repository/html/images/image.gif
warning: changegroup hook exited with status 255
```

Additional Permission Information:

- All 3 files in the 2 changesets have 775 permission with the webuser:dev user:group.
- My Global hgrc file has the webuser trusted

  ```
  [trusted]
  users = webuser
  ```

Comment: Perhaps there was a permissions issue for the file in question?

Comment: Based on the debug output, I have to agree.  I appended details regarding the permissions on the server.  Please let me know your thoughts on how to resolve this permission issue.

Comment: This comment shows a little confusion "All 3 files in the 2 changesets have 775 permission with the webuser:dev user:group".  Files in changesets don't have file permission (excepting execute) or users or groups -- those metadata aren't track by mercurial so they're not parts of files in changesets.  The files on disk, both those in .hg and those in the working directory, will have ownership and permissions based only on who was running the mercurial command that wrote them.  In your example that's 'levinaris', not webuser.

Comment: That makes sense.  I was referring to the permissions of the files as they appear on the linux server's filesystem.  What is the debug output referring to when it states "update permissions -> e"?

Comment: (Continued) If levinaris is non-superuser that user won't be able to create files that are webuser:dev nor chmod files over to it.  You can, however, use the sticky group bit to get the group on any new files set to 'dev', which if your umask is creating things at 7775 is probably sufficient.

Comment: If that is the case, why would this problem only exist for the two images and not the index.php also?  I'm not doubting you, but I am curious.

Comment: Perhaps they're only getting the bad owner/group info if they're re-created, which might depend on whether or not they were still hardlinked from their initial clone or if the link had been broken by a previous update that updated index.html but not image.gif?  Just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that the permissions that file on the server were such that it couldn't be overwitten by the person doing the push?

If, for example, two different people have done that push (and thus update) the second person isn't going to be able to overwrite the files created by the first person's push triggered update.

Maybe try changing the hook to this for a test (you don't actually have those single quotes on your hook, right?):

```
[hooks]
changegroup = hg --debug update
```

If it is a permissions issue the usual fix is to put everyone who will be pushing and updating into the same group (I call mine 'hg') and then using the sticky group bit on all the directories in the repo to make sure new files have that group.

Comment: I'll edit the original post.  I did not have those backticks in the config file or the error output.  It was a mistake in formatting my post here.

Comment: I'm not positive regarding the permissions... The files that update without issue and the ones that cause the "abort" error all have the same permissions on the filesystem: Owned by the web user, in the dev group.  Are there other permissions that I should be checking?  Maybe something Mercurial-specific?

Comment: I appended the result of the `hg --debug update` to my original post.  Please let me your thoughts.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm chiming in in the comments on the questions, but I imagine we'll get there.  It certainly seems like permissions.

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  As it turns out, a cron had been placed on the server which was changing the permissions and owners of files every five minutes or so.  I'm guessing that the cron happened to run while a push/update was being run, thus causing this issue.